# Chrome not registering click

Tags: google-chrome, browser, input, compatibility

This page: http://rippertshirts.co.uk/products/bazinga-t-shirt-brand-new-funny-geeky-big-bang-theory-ripper-s-m-l-xl/

I cannot add an item to the cart in Google Chrome.

Here is the input:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="Cart66ButtonPrimary purAddToCart" name="addToCart_68" id="addToCart_68" disabled="disabled">
```

Can anyone think of a reason for this? Could it be the disabled="disabled feature"

I tried adding this to my header.php but no luck :(

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
    $(".Cart66ButtonPrimary").click(function(){
        $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
        return(true);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Um, disabled mean you can not click...So Chrome is working as expected. You need to find the code that is setting it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler since you'are putting your jQuery code in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
$(function() {
    $(".Cart66ButtonPrimary").click(function(){
        $("input:text").removeAttr("disabled");
        return(true);
    });
});
```